# How to add node js packages to Meteor app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, meteor, node-modules

I am trying to get Express and Multer Node.js packages to work with Meteor 1.7, but I am ending up with error messages.

I followed this tutorial https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/using-npm-packages and took the following steps to install Express and Multer packages:

1. created a new meteor project
2. ran `meteor npm install express multer --save` command
3. imported the two packages to the app via api.js file (imported to both server and client during dev), which reads:

   ```
   import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
   import multer from 'multer';
   import express from 'express';
   const app = express();
   app.use(function (req, res, next) {
       console.log('Time:', Date.now())
       next()
   });
   ```
4. In the system console, I get the following error:

> TypeError: express is not a function

and Meteor exits with:

> code 1 ==> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi kv2016, Welcome to SO! Looking at the code you've posted, this sould 100% work. Can you try using `require` instead of import? (like the express docs say). Under the hood Meteor treats `require` the same as a default import

Comment: Also, since express relies on NodeJS providing a http server, it should not be imported on the client

Comment: And are you sure you ran `npm install` in the right folder?

Comment: Hello Fred. Thank you for your answers! I am running the `npm install` command in the root folder of the meteor project.  Changing to `require` also doesn't help, nor does importing the functions to the servers side (which is the plan). The issue persists with express not being recognised as a function, which must do with it being incorrectly imported, but I don't see why

Comment: Maybe try deleting `node_modules` and running `npm install` again? That often fixes npm import related issues

Comment: Just to make sure, I did exactly the same thing in a new project and it worked straight away: https://github.com/coagmano/so-question-52377183/commit/433f394c24715e107949497ed857d3ea06bad2cf

Comment: Ok, I think I found the caveat. I kept Meteor running in localhost while installing npm packages and thought that the server would import the new packages as it always restarts when the code changes. Just ran console.log(express) on the server, which outputs with a list of functions now.  However, when I was experimenting with some Atmosphere packages yesterday, they worked straight out of the box without needing to shutdown Meteor localhost. Thanks everyone

Comment: Normally this does, so it must have been an anomaly

Comment: Node packages don't automatically reload as Meteor is an extension to Node, while Atmosphere packages are built specifically for Meteor.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure if you can use express with meteor. Meteor has a built in WebApp module which you can use to add custom routing if that is what you are trying to do

https://docs.meteor.com/packages/webapp.html